# Copy contents of one array to another with pointers

Tags: c++

I've been learning C++ on my own for a while now, and I've come to a "roadblock" when it comes to pointers. I'm using this as my http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ learning material, but I'm still having an issue. So to test something I wanted to copy the contents of one array into another. I wrote the following.

```
char arrayA[15] = "abcdef";
char arrayB[15];

char *a = arrayA;
char *b = arrayB;

cout << "before loop:" << endl;
cout << a << endl;
cout << b << endl;

while (*a != '\0') {
    // Copy the contents of a into b
    *b = *a;

    // Step
    a++;
    b++;
}

// Assign null to the end of arrayB
*b = '\0';

cout << "after loop:" << endl;
cout << a << endl;
cout << b << endl;
```

I get the following results.

```
before loop:
abcdef

after loop:
```

When I `cout` the contents before the loop I get the expected results. `a` contains "abcdef" and `b` is nothing, because there is no value yet. Now after the loop, both `a` and `b` show no results. This is where I am lost. I used `*` to dereference both `a` and `b` and assign the value of `a` into `b`. Where did I go wrong? Do I need to use the `&` with this?

**Solution:**

After the loop is complete, pointer `*a` is pointing to the end of arrayA and pointer `*b` is pointing to the end of arrayB. So to get the full results of arrayB simply `cout << arrayB`. Or create a pointer that never changes and always points to arrayB `char *c = arrayB` and `cout << c` at the end of the loop.

Comment: Note that NULL is not the null character, which is written as '\0'. NULL is a C macro denoting a null pointer, and shouldn't be used in C++ (for pointers, use the new literal nullptr, or simply 0).

Comment: @Peter Schneider Thank you. Made the necessary changes.

Comment: Oh, and don't use an uninitialized array, e.g. for output (like with arrayB after "beforeLoop"). Write a '\0' in the first char so that it becomes an empty string. Your program works only coincidentally (unless the arrays are global in which case they are zeroed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the loop `a` and `b` have changed, they then point to the end of the string. You need to make a copy of the pointers to step through so that as you iterate you're not changing the location of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're outputting your temporary variables that were used to iterate through the array.  They are now at the end of the copied data.  You should output the value of `arrayA` and `arrayB` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remember begin of array. In this moment you are incrementing pointers and printing something which is pointed by them at the end of arrays, after loop ends.

```
char arrayA[15] = "abcdef";
char arrayB[15];

char *a_beg = arrayA;
char *b_beg = arrayB;
char *a;
char *b;

cout << "before loop:" << endl;
cout << a_beg << endl;
cout << b_beg << endl;

a = a_beg;
b = b_beg;
while (*a != '\0') {
    // copy contents of a into b and increment
    *b++ = *a++;
}
// assign null to the end of arrayB
*b = '\0';

cout << "after loop:" << endl;
cout << a_beg << endl;
cout << b_beg << endl;
```